# Shorter declaration for inputs in Sass

Tags: css, sass

Inputs and buttons have a lot of predefined styles, that had been reseted in the first place, for example borders and backrounds. If borders and backgrounds are styled later differenty, is there a way to make the declaration shorter?

```
.mybutton1,
[role="button"].mybutton1,
input[type="submit"].mybutton1,
input[type="rest"].mybutton1,
input[type="button"].mybutton1,
button.mybutton1 { {
font-size: 10px;    
background-color: red;
border: solid;

}

.mybutton2,
[role="button"].mybutton2,
input[type="submit"].mybutton2,
input[type="rest"].mybutton2,
input[type="button"].mybutton2,
button.mybutton2 { {
font-size: 10px;
background-color: blue; 
}
```

Comment: if .mybutton1 and .mybutton2 isn't strong enought (so you have to prefix it with input[type=..]) pls check why you have to be so specific. IMO .mybutton1 and .mybutton2 should be good enought.

Comment: input and button have a lot of predefined styles, that had been reseted in the first place, for example borders and backrounds. If borders and backgrounds are styled late you need to do it like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use common style in to input styles and differentiate with your class, check below codes.

```
[role="button"],
input[type="submit"],
input[type="rest"],
input[type="button"],
button {
  font-size: 8px;
}

.mybutton1 {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.mybutton2 {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nikhilvkd/s12643k1/

**[Updated]**

OR

You can do with sass like below codes

```
@mixin buttonStyle($class, $fontSize) {
  [role="button"].#{$class},
  input[type="submit"].#{$class},
  input[type="rest"].#{$class},
  input[type="button"].#{$class},
  button.#{$class} {
    font-size: $fontSize;
  }
}
@include buttonStyle(mybutton1, 20px);
@include buttonStyle(mybutton2, 40px);
@include buttonStyle(mybutton3, 60px);
```

Fiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/nikhilvkd/s12643k1/1/

Note: First method is more good for less css codes

Comment: input and button have a lot of predefined styles, that had been reseted in the first place, for example borders and backrounds. If borders and backgrounds are styled late you need to do it like that. Sorry I forgot to add my reset.

Comment: Then please completed your question first

Answer (score 0):

You can use mixins for that I guess:

```
@mixin generate_size($class_num, $size) {
   .mybutton{$class_num},
   [role="button"].mybutton{$class_num},
   input[type="submit"].mybutton{$class_num},
   input[type="rest"].mybutton{$class_num},
   input[type="button"].mybutton{$class_num},
   button.mybutton{$class_num}
      { font-size: $size; }
}
@include generate_size("1", 10px);
@include generate_size("2", 15px);
```